# The Second Time Binding Of ListView raised event Sorting/Editing Exception

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a ListView which gets filled from search results, and the first time I view the results in the ListView, I can sort as many times as I want with no problem. But when I run another search and hit the search button (which just refreshes the datasource of the ListView to the results) then I get the error:

> The ListView 'lvCustomer' raised event Sorting which wasn't handled.

And then if i edit any item again then i get following error:

> The ListView 'lvCustomer' raised event ItemEditing which wasn't handled.

I have it reassign the select statement to the sqldata source and rebind the ListView . I do this because if I don't the List displays everything in the database. But I don't think this has anything to do with the error.
First Time I am using object datasource. Second time I am using a dataset. here is the code I am using to rebind it.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{       
    string name = txtSearch.Text;    
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();       
    ds = QMS_BLL.GetCustomers.GetCumtomerByName(name);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)  
    {        
        lvCustomer.DataSourceID = "";
        lvCustomer.DataSource = ds;  
        lvCustomer.DataBind();                
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply Edited My Object data-source , and Wrote the second method too into that data source.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCustomers" runat="server" 
                DeleteMethod="DeleteCustomers" InsertMethod="InsertCustomers" 
                SelectMethod="GetCumtomers" TypeName="QMS_BLL.Customers" 
                UpdateMethod="UpdateCustomers">
            <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="searchName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

I Hope It Will Help Someone Out In Future.Thanks!